# maven not adding dependency in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: maven, restfb

I have a maven project B which is packaged as a war B.war and has a 'local' dependency A.jar. The pom for building A.jar has a dependency on restFB and it resolves properly while compiling.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
        <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        <version>${com.restfb-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

However when I package B.war, restFB's jar is not present in the WEB-INF/lib directory of B.war and execution throws NoClassDefFoundError. What is also baffling is that I find this happening only when I build it on an AWS Amazon Linux and not while building on Ubuntu. There are similar questions in SO which suggest adding

```
         <packaging>war</packaging>
```

which I already have but doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: just for confirmation ,your settings.xml is same in both environments and scope of the restFb dependency is same i.e should be compile because i dont think your web container will provide required classes at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be simple to understand, that you might have invoke locally under Ubuntu

```
mvn install
```

for *A*. Therefore it is in the local .m2 repository.

Did AWS Amazon Linux also have this artifact in its repository? If not, copy it there and try to package again.

Also you explicitly **include** and exclude certain artifacts within the build configuration for *maven-war-plugin*

Comment: why it wont't download from Maven central repository if it is not available local M2 repository ?

Comment: yes, if the Maven central repository has the artifact. Did you check? It might be helpful if you could post the verbose output of mvn package.

Comment: All right! mvn install did the trick. However I remember checking this and I did find restfb in the m2 repo in my Amazon linux instance when it wouldn't package. So a mystery?